# 8TB external hard drive filling up after only 3 TB used, 5TB reported as "inaccessible"

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, external-disk

I've got an 8 TB expansion drive. When I rsync data to it, it's reporting as filled up after only receiving 3 TB. The gui diskutil shows it as 8TB. The command line diskutil shows this:

```
/dev/disk6 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *8.0 TB     disk6
   1:         Microsoft Reserved                         134.2 MB   disk6s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk7         8.0 TB     disk6s2

/dev/disk7 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +8.0 TB     disk7
                                 Physical Store disk6s2
   1:                APFS Volume Seagate Expansi         7.9 TB     disk7s1
```

and

```
> $ df -h /Volumes/Seagate\ Expansi
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk7s1  7.3Ti  7.2Ti   63Gi   100% 23651283 663255720    3%   /Volumes/Seagate Expansi
```

Though the above says I've used 7.2Ti, I am not. Running some disk space analyzer software, it's repoting over 5TB as "inaccessible", pictured here in the light blue.

[image]

Comment: 1) My external disks all show partition 1 as EFI, not Microsoft Reserved (I don't know if this is important). What was used to erase and format it? 2) Is this reproducible? I.e. what happens if you now erase the disk with Disk Utility (or diskutil) and repeat the rsync command?

Comment: I'm in the process of moving the data off the drive to try to reformat it.

Answer (score 1):

I moved the files off the external drive and used Disk Utility to erase the drive. The software I use to check free disk space no longer reports the space as inaccessible but "free."